# Send Email by checking a value from Webapplication

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am calculating volume and percentage of a tank using a sensor and sending data from Azure IOT hub to Azure table storage .Now I created a webapplication and deployed to azure.
Now I want to send an email alert if the percentage value is less than 20.

Could someone please guide to how to proceed with Microsoft Azure? Is it possible with Logic apps?If Yes,Can you please provide the work flow?

Many Thanks in advance

[image: WebappURL]
[image: Logicapp cretetime]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email alert Azure table storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526894/email-alert-azure-table-storage)

Comment: Have you checked the answers from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526894/email-alert-azure-table-storage)? I posted the answer and provided the detailed work flow for Logic apps, you could refer to it.

Comment: Yes.I have checked the answer for the previous question.I am sending data for every 10min and status column in table storage is changed as either true or false.So I am recieving mails for all records which has true value.(if there are 100 records with status=true,I will have 100 emails).Is there any option in logic apps to receive email for only recent record.If yes,Could you please tell me the procedure? or Can I send an email depending upon the value from webapplication using Azure? Many Thanks in advance

Comment: The default value for status is false. The **Get entities** and the **condition** block would only handle the records with the status equals false. Are you mean that the previous record(s) which has been marked as checked would still send the email?  If so, your need to check with your flow. For receiving email for only recent record, you could also add the custom column `createTime` and check the it in your logic app condition block.

Comment: yes.the previous records that are marked as checked also send the email.I tried to add another column 'createtime' but how to add time time automatically so that I can send email for only recent recors?Could you pelase send the workflow for cretetime column?Please find the attached image.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the `utcnow()` date function under Expression tab. For more details, you could refer to [Workflow Definition Language schema for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language).

Answer (score 1):

> or Can I send an email depending upon the value from webapplication using Azure?

You could use [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) which works as a background task under your azure website. You could leverage the [TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger) for retrieving records from your table storage and process your logic periodically. For retrieving data from table storage, you could use [Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), more details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#retrieve-a-range-of-entities-in-a-partition). For sending emails, you could leverage the SendGrid binding for webjobs. You could follow [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) for more detailed code sample for TimerTrigger and SendGrid binding within your webjob.